# Using parameter bind anotations @properties is null

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Iam using Parameter Binding Annotations @Properties as argument  and it is null.The exchange properties are not binded to the argument.

Camel version : 2.17

Container : Jboss EAP 6.4

Camel Bean definition:

```
 <bean id="_bean1"
                method="methodA('serviceName')" ref="eventLogger"/>
```

Java method definition:

```
public void methodA(String eventName,@Properties Map<String, Object> properties) {

        //do something;
    }
```

Can you please help with this issue

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your code. Should work. What's the `eventLogger` definition? I've seem errors using mock endpoints and `@Properties` bind before. Are you testing using mocks? If positive, try without it.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue .I had packaged war along with the dependency libraries and it had a copy of camel core.the calling class was created as a module and added as a dependency to the war package as provided.it was loading camel core classes individually.After referring the camel core from both custom module and war from the system modules it is working fine.